# Strange SUM causing "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type money"?

Tags: sql-server

Firstly this seems to only happen when using a `JOIN` in the query, without joining, the `SUM` just works.

Suppose I have 2 tables `TableA`, `TableB` (references `TableA` via `AId` column),
`TableB.Value` has data type of `money`.

```
-- this throws the overflow exception
select sum(TableB.Value) 
from TableA
     join TableB on TableA.Id = TableB.AId
group by TableA.Id
```

As you can see, the input value for `SUM` is `TableB.Value`, so basically if we don't use `JOIN`, we can write it simply like this (just to test if overflowing happens):

```
select sum(TableB.Value)
from TableB
group by AId
```

I expected this has an overflow error as well but it works without any error.
So it's very strange this way.

I think this can be reproduced with dummy data somehow (but I don't have such data to upload here). I hope you could still guess or explain what is wrong here?

**Please note** that I need some explanation for this first, I do know one way to avoid the exception being thrown by casting the `TableB.Value` to `decimal(19,4)` first.

**UPDATE**

The `TableB` has a lot of rows with `AId` being null. The sum of `TableB.Value` grouped on that `null` will cause the overflow exception. But looks like when joining, all those null `AId`s are involved somehow?

So if filtering out all those null `AId`s, it works:

```
select sum(TableB.Value) 
from TableA
     join (select * from TableB 
           where AId is not null) v
     on TableA.Id = v.AId
group by TableA.Id
```

Comment: The error is telling you the problem, you are ending up with a value too large for the `money` data type. So the `SUM` is either less  than -922,337,203,685,477.5808 or greater than 922,337,203,685,477.5807.

Comment: @Larnu if the data source has some very large value, why the second snippet works?

Comment: It's not "strange" at all, as very likely the reason it gets so large/small is because of said `JOIn` being a many-to-many, causing a much larger/smaller value than when you didn't have the `JOIN`.

Comment: Just because something has `Id` in its name doesn't make it unique. Probably there are many rows matching `TableA.Id = TableB.AId`, causing the sum to expand.

Comment: @Larnu that's a good point, but here is an `inner-join`, so I don't see why it could produce more rows in the `TableA` has when not using JOIN. So it's not very obvious here.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the `Id` is ensured unique on `TableA`, but of course not on `TableB` (referenced as `AId`).

Comment: Again, because you have a many-to-many relationship, @Hopeless , and thus you are (likely) counting the *same* value of `TableA.Value` multiple times. The result of the following query is `63` (`(12 * 2) + (13 * 3)`) not `25` (`12+13`): `SELECT SUM(A.I) FROM (VALUES(1,12),(2,13)) A(ID,I) JOIN (VALUES(1,10),(1,9),(2,12),(2,25),(2,17))B(ID,I) ON A.ID = B.ID;`

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to achieve with the `JOIN` in the above? You don't return any of the values from said table, so why the `JOIN`?

Comment: @Larnu sorry, there are some mistake in my question, I updated the question. The relationship between A & B is just `one-many`, one A - many B. Please review it again, thanks.

Comment: That just further cements my point, @Hopeless . One to many/many to many, you have a *many* relationship.

Comment: @Larnu with `one-many` relationship, the JOIN cannot produce more rows than the table B has, the SUM is not on the tableA, it's on the TableB. If it's on the table A, I can understand the point why JOIN could make a difference here.

Comment: If a row in `A` joins to `B` twice then you have **two** rows, @Hopeless , so you are `SUM`ing the value in `A` *twice*. If a row in `A` joins to `B` 700 times, you would `SUM` the same value **700** times.

Comment: @Larnu no, I sum on B, not A, please look at it again.

Comment: @Larnu the purpose of joining with table A here is just to reference it (from B) and add some more filter (not included in the question to make it simpler).

Comment: Try to identify the AIds that cause the overflow, maybe there is something overlooked.. https://dbfiddle.uk/JYeNdJLv

Comment: @lptr I'm trying to reproduce it but not succeeded yet despite all what I've figured out so far.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be your misunderstanding of how `JOIN`s and `SUM`s work.

Let's take the following 2 tables:

##### TableA

| ID | I |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 13 |

##### TableB

| ID | A_ID | I |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 17 |
| 2 | 1 | 12 |
| 3 | 2 | 7 |
| 4 | 2 | 19 |
| 5 | 3 | 1 |

Now take the following query:

```sql
SELECT SUM(I) AS SumI
FROM dbo.TableA;
```

This would result in the value `25`: `12 + 13`

Now let's take the following query, which you effectively have.

```
SELECT SUM(A.I) AS SumI
FROM dbo.TableA A;
     JOIN abo.TableB B On A.ID = B.A_ID;
```

This would result in the value `63` *not* `25`. This is because you have a many to one relationship. As a result the actual `SUM` would be `12 + 12 + 13 + 13 + 13` or `(12 * 2) + (13 * 3)`.

This can be better seen if you remove the aggregation:

```sql
SELECT A.ID,
       A.I
FROM dbo.TableA A;
     JOIN abo.TableB B On A.ID = B.A_ID;
```

This will return the following:

| ID | I |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 1 | 12 |
| 2 | 13 |
| 2 | 13 |
| 2 | 13 |

I suspect what you actually need is something like an `EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT SUM(A.I)
FROM dbo.TableA A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.TableB B
              WHERE B.A_ID = A.ID);
```

This will return `25`.

Comment: please take a look at it one more time carefully, I sum the values on the table B (which is the `many-end`), but your example is different (like the original question of mine). Really sorry about that wrong original question.

Comment: Then provide DDL and DML to reproduce the problem, @Hopeless . I still am under the impression you have a one/many-to-many relationship and thus you are under the impression that the `SUM` of a non-`JOIN`ed query should equal that of a `JOIN`ed query.

Comment: I have basic knowledge about relationships in sql as well as how JOIN works. I just made a mistake while writing the question with an example in which all the tables are renamed (because I don't want to show my actual script). Of course I'll try to reproduce this with an example, but as I said in the question, someone may guess what could cause such an error.

Comment: I think I've found a clue here, the `TableB` actually has a lot of rows having `AId` of `null`. Of course when joining I don't think such null `AId` can be involved somehow.

Of course in the second snippet, I have to actually filter out all those `null` `AId` before grouping by `AId` (which will make the SUM cause the overflow exception on that `null` group). I hope you can base on this clue to update your answer. Thanks.